# Uploading Video to video Library using SharePoint2013 Rest APIs

Tags: rest, video, sharepoint-2013

I am using SharePoint RestAPIs to upload video to Video Library using the following urls and the video is uploaded successfully:

1._api/web/lists/getbytitle('Video Library')/rootfolder/Files/add(url='a.mp4')

2._api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Video Library')/Files/add(url='a.mp4')

The issue is that the AJAX calling are return in the error method(file not found) not in the success method and I want to use the file url after uploading

Note the following:

1.when you upload a video to video library SharePoint create a folder with the name of the uploaded video file name and put the video file inside it.

2.If you already uploaded a file with the same name SharePoint create the folder with random name and put the video inside it.